# Batch Prediction in Tensorflow session run

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am pretty new to Tensorflow and I would like to know when I load a frozen graph for prediction, is it possible to do a batch prediction like in keras.

My code looks like the following in Tensorflow :

```
path='some_path.pb'
with dgraph.as_default():
     od_graph_def=tf.GraphDef()
     with tf.gfile.GFile(path,'rb') as fid:
          serialized_graph=fid.read()
          od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
          tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def,name='')
sess = tf.Session(graph=dgraph)   

feat_5=detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('Relu6:0')
input=np.random.randn(100,300,300,3)

sess.run([feat_5],feed_dict={image_tensor: input}) **want to add batches of data here instead of input directly
```

Comment: Your code looks correct in general. What is it exactly that you want to get that you cannot do with your current code? Assuming your network works with images, wouldn't `input` here, with shape `(100, 300, 300, 3)`, be a batch of images?

Comment: So I want to run through the input in batches of size e.g 10. How would I do that ?
In keras one can do this in the following way :
`Feat_vgg=feat_Vmodel.predict(vgg_batch,**batch_size=20**)`